# Nothing was returned from render, GraphQL, Nextjs, and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, jsx

Every condition seems to be covered and the query is returning the right data. Is there something I am missing? Is the function children not formatted properly?

Error: Query(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

```js
import CATEGORIES_QUERY from "../queries/categories";

import Link from 'next/link'

import Query from "../helpers/query";

export default function Nav() {
    return (
            <div className="flex justify-between container mx-auto bg-gray-700">
                <span className="font-bold text-green-600 hover:text-green-400 border-b-4 border-green-600 hover:border-green-400 hover:translate-y-8 hover:shadow-lg ">
                    Uenunciate
                </span>
                <nav className="flex justify-between">
                    <ul className="flex flex-wrap mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8">
                        <Query query={CATEGORIES_QUERY} id={null}>
                            {
                                ( { data: { categories } } ) => {
                                    return (categories.map(
                                        (category) => {
                                            return (
                                                <li key={category.slug} className="mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8 text-green-600 hover:text-green-400 border-b-4 border-green-600 hover:border-green-400 hover:translate-y-8 hover:shadow-lg ">
                                                    <Link href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
                                                        {category.name}
                                                    </Link>
                                                </li>
                                            );
                                        }
                                    )) || null; 
                                }
                            }
                        </Query>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        
    )
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const Query = ({ children, query, slug }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: { slug: slug }
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;

  return children({ data });
};

export default Query;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you might return something like`<>{chidren(data)}</>`. your code looks extremely confusing with a lot of weird data pass backward and forward without reason. Maybe try to simply a bit to make it pass from regular parent to children with props.

Comment: Yeah, I was following a tutorial and that was the method they used. Removed the passing of data back and forth and just used the hook in the Nav function and checked the loading/error conditions with turnery logic in the return statement; this worked fine. I did try your suggestion before and it didn't work.

Comment: Instead of using the `Query` component, just create another `<NavItem />` , call your Apollo query inside and replace the `Query` link entirely in `Nav`. The extraction of `Query` component in "my opinion" does not bring any benefits since you need to modify query options a lot based on your rendering. and even sometimes you don't want to do `if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;` in pagination. I felt bit it's too early to refactor for this case. You might want to judge the tutorial by yourself sometimes. If it makes sense later in the tutorial, then you can still make the change like them

Comment: Many tutorials just use existing codebase and replicated the code in a way. So they tends to ignore the process behind. create A B C then extract the common D from them. They just create D first then do ABC, which can be misleading, You might want to be aware of that.